# Is there an Addon for Thunderbird 3 which will show me a fixed website in a tab?

Tags: plugins, thunderbird

I'm looking for a Thunderbird 3 addon which will show me a fixed website in a tab. I don't need navigational components, just the one website.

(Explanation: Due to the lack of a compatible version of the Lightning-Plugin, I would like to be able to switch to the Google Calendar-website within the Thunderbird application.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ThunderBrowse](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/thunderbird/addon/5373) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: It's slight overkill, but a start.

Answer (score 1):

I found an addon for my particular case: [Google Calendar in Thunderbird Tabs](http://clarkbw.net/blog/2009/11/23/google-calendar-in-thunderbird-tabs/).